# Gerar uma palavra entre palavras definidas [PHP]

Tags: php, random

Sou bem novo em `PHP`, mas já conheço o básico de `HTML`, e uma grande parte de `Ruby script` (não `ruby on rails`).

Bom, quer saber, como posso gerar uma palavra ou algo aleatório, podemos dizer, mas não tanto aleatório. Como se fosse para gerar uma palavra de um "banco de dados". Por exemplo:

Eu defino no meu código duas palavras: *Linguagem*, *Língua* e *Lang*.
Quero fazer o php gerar uma delas, mas não gerar algo como idioma, ou qualquer coisa que não seja *Linguagem*, *Língua* ou *Lang*.

Comment: Você tem uma lista de palavras e quer escolher uma aleatoriamente?

Comment: exatamente. isso que preciso

Answer (score 3):

Podes fazer assim:

```
$palavras = array('Linguagem', 'Língua', 'Lang');
$aleatorio = rand(0, 2);
echo $palavras[$aleatorio];
```

#### Exemplo: https://ideone.com/ZvMkec

Defines uma array com as palavras que queres usar, e depois o [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) para gerar um numero aleatório. O método [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) permite indicar o numero minimo e máximo, repara que usei 0 e 2 porque o indice de arrays começa em zero.

Podes fazer simplesmente `$aleatorio = rand(0, count($palavras) - 1);` e fica independente do numero de elementos da array.

Exemplo usando `rand(0, count($palavras) - 1);` e uma função: https://ideone.com/TfQMa5

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado, resolveu minha dúvida!

Comment: Eu usaria ainda `count($palavras)-1` como valor máximo do `rand()`

Comment: @DiogoDoreto bem visto, coloquei agora mesmo antes do teu comment, e será `count($palavras) -1`.

Comment: Pois é, vi no momento em que postei ;)

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar `shuffle` para embaralhar o array e usar `current` para retornar o primeiro elemento.

```
$array = array( 'Linguagem', 'Língua', 'Lang' );

shuffle( $array );
echo current( $array );
```

[Exemplo](https://ideone.com/w4XRH8)

Comment: Se o array for grande, terá problemas de performance com esse método