# Gerador de palavras aleatórias em PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer um gerador de palavras aleatórias, onde através de um botão(Rodar ou Girar), ele busque em um arquivo `txt` externo, ou até mesmo de um banco de dados, a palavra e mostre para na tela.

A ideia é um sistema parecido com o soletrando, onde eu terei 3 níveis do básico ao avançado.

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Tentei a solução do colega do link abaixo mas não é bem o que eu preciso.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67838/gerar-uma-palavra-entre-palavras-definidas-php

Comment: Se você usar um arquivo com as palavras separadas por uma quebra de linha, você pode usar a função `file` para ler esse arquivo e depois fazer como sugere a resposta indicada.